# finding vals from table with variable keys

Tags: java, algorithm

There is a table:

[image]

key consists from 3 suffixes:
region+s1+s2

region, like US is always specified, but other ones can be not specified so * will be used for "all".

for example:
for key = "US_A_U" value = 2, because:

1. trying to find full match: find in the table key ("US_A_U") - not
   found
2. 1 step less strict find: find key ("US_A_*") - found == 2

for key = "US_Q_Q" value = 3, because:

1. trying to find full match: find in the table key ("US_Q_Q") - not
   found
2. 1 step less strict find: find key ("US_Q_*") - not found
3. find key ("US_*_Q") - not found
4. 1 step less strict find: find key ("`US_*_*`") - found = 3

for key = "US_O_P" value = 3, because:

1. trying to find full match: find in the table key ("US_O_P") - not
   found
2. 1 step less strict find: find key ("US_O_*") - not found
3. find key ("US_*_P") - not found
4. 1 step less strict find: find key ("`US_*_*`") - found = 3

so to use HashMap method I will need to call 4 times map.get() to find a value, which is too many as this code will be run very very often.

Is there any nicer or faster solutions?

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainCLass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // init map (assuming this code will be run only once)
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("US_A_B", "1");
        map.put("US_A_*", "2");
        map.put("US_*_*", "3");
        map.put("US_O_O", "4");
        map.put("US_*_W", "5");
        map.put("ASIA_*_*", "6");

        // now often called logic
        // incoming params, for this example hardcoded
        String reg = "US";
        String s1 = "O";
        String s2 = "P";
        String val = null;
        val = map.get(reg+"_"+s1+"_"+s2);
        if (val == null){
            val = map.get(reg+"_"+s1+"_*");
            if (val == null){
                val = map.get(reg+"_"+"*_"+s2);
                if (val == null){
                    val = map.get(reg+"_*_*");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

**upd:** I need to add that there are always 3 incoming params (region, s1, s2). Each of this param never will equal `"*"` and never be empty, so the full key always be like `US_J_K` (and not `US_*_K` etc.)

so by these 3 params I need to find right value from the init table.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate

Comment: Use guava's Table data structure. It suits your needs perfectly. See here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28252/class-for-map-of-maps  OR, try out the other answer from that link

Comment: Did you really identify this part of our code being the bottleneck in your algorithm using these values? Then congratulations. As a solution: you could precompute all missing values on initialization, at least if `s1` and `s2` consist of only one char.

Comment: by "*" you mean any characters is that it?

Comment: @sad_cat yes, for example, `US_*_B` means: for input params where region=US, s1=ANY STRING, s2=B

Comment: If you have two possibles which one to you choose? the most founded ?

Comment: @sad_cat for case where we have `US_*_A` and `US_B_*` and input key is `US_B_A` - we'll just get value for any of them, doesn't matter which one

Comment: I am not sure if your performance problem comes from the 4 time map.get().. hashtable.get(key) has `O(1)`, shouldn't be the bottleneck.

Comment: Exactly. In worst case you will always call `get` from the map 4times. Even Dragon's answer does that but in a facny way

Comment: (Trying to wrap my head around this: why not 5) `*_s1_s2` 6) `*_s1_*` 7) `*_*_s2`?) (care for me to try and unify the _key_ representations in the question?)

Comment: @greybeard `region, like US is always specified`

Comment: (I forgot that you specify "the star/don't care/unspecified entries" explicitly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a tier of maps such as

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> map;
```

In this map the first key is region, the second key is s1, and the third key is s2. This will allow To easily search for region, s1, and s2 independently.

EDIT:

Example usage with searching for "US_O_P"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RegionMap map = new RegionMap();
    String region = "US";
    String s1 = "O";
    String s2 = "P";
    String val = map.search(region, s1, s2);
    System.out.println(val);
}

public class RegionMap {
    private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> regionMap;

    public RegionMap() {
        init();
    }

    public String search(String region, String s1, String s2) {
        String val = searchS1(regionMap.get(region), s1, s2);
        if (val == null) {
            val = searchS1(regionMap.get("*"), s1, s2);
        }
        return val;
    }

    private String searchS1(Map<String, Map<String, String>> s1Map, String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1Map == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String val = searchS2(s1Map.get(s1), s2);
        if (val == null) {
            val = searchS2(s1Map.get("*"), s2);
        }
        return val;
    }

    private String searchS2(Map<String, String> s2Map, String s2) {
        if (s2Map == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String val = s2Map.get(s2);
        if (val == null) {
            val = s2Map.get("*");
        }
        return val;
    }

    private void init() {
        regionMap = new HashMap<>();
        addEntry("US", "A", "B", "1");
        addEntry("US", "A", "*", "2");
        addEntry("US", "*", "*", "3");
        addEntry("US", "O", "O", "4");
        addEntry("US", "*", "W", "5");
        addEntry("ASIA", "*", "*", "6");
    }

    private void addEntry(String region, String s1, String s2, String value) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> s1Map = regionMap.get(region);
        if (s1Map == null) {
            s1Map = new HashMap<>();
            regionMap.put(region, s1Map);
        }

        Map<String, String> s2Map = s1Map.get(s1);
        if (s2Map == null) {
            s2Map = new HashMap<>();
            s1Map.put(s1, s2Map);
        }

        s2Map.put(s2, value);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Benchmark results

I ran tests for searching for "US_O_P" multiple times and found the following results for 1,000,000,000 searches

```
Original: 9.7334702479 seconds
Tiered: 2.471287074 seconds
```

The following is the benchmark code

```
public class RegionMapOrig {
    private Map<String, String> map;

    public RegionMapOrig() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("US_A_B", "1");
        map.put("US_A_*", "2");
        map.put("US_*_*", "3");
        map.put("US_O_O", "4");
        map.put("US_*_W", "5");
        map.put("ASIA_*_*", "6");
    }

    public String search(String reg, String s1, String s2) {
        String val = null;
        val = map.get(reg + "_" + s1 + "_" + s2);
        if (val == null) {
            val = map.get(reg + "_" + s1 + "_*");
            if (val == null) {
                val = map.get(reg + "_" + "*_" + s2);
                if (val == null) {
                    val = map.get(reg + "_*_*");
                }
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
}

private static final int N = 1000000000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String region = "US";
    String s1 = "O";
    String s2 = "P";

    testOrig(region, s1, s2);
    test(region, s1, s2);
}

private static void testOrig(String region, String s1, String s2) {
    RegionMapOrig map = new RegionMapOrig();

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        String val = map.search(region, s1, s2);
    }

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 10E9);
}

private static void test(String region, String s1, String s2) {
    RegionMap map = new RegionMap();

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        String val = map.search(region, s1, s2);
    }

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 10E9);
}
```

Running this code multiple times have yielded the same results. However, this benchmark is a simple and may not be definitive. To truly test your results you will need to analyze the performance with a real data set that represents your typical values. I believe your performance issue may lie within your string concatenation and not how many calls to the map. The other reason why mine may have performed better is that my internal maps may be cached making multiple retrievals faster.

EDIT: Benchmark update

After further investigation by removing string concatentation your original code improved showing these results:

```
Orginal (no concatentation): 1.2068575417 seconds
Tiered: 2.2982665873 seconds
```

The code changes are:

```
public String searchNoCat(String cache1, String cache2, String cache3,  String cache4) {
    String val = null;
    val = map.get(cache1);
    if (val == null) {
        val = map.get(cache2);
        if (val == null) {
            val = map.get(cache3);
            if (val == null) {
                val = map.get(cache4);
            }
        }
    }
    return val;
}

private static void testOrigNoCat(String region, String s1, String s2) {
    RegionMapOrig map = new RegionMapOrig();

    String cache1 = region + "_" + s1 + "_" + s2;
    String cache2 = region + "_" + s1 + "_*";
    String cache3 = region + "_" + "*_" + s2;
    String cache4 = region + "_*_*";

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        String val = map.searchNoCat(cache1, cache2, cache3, cache4);
    }

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 10E9);
}
```

However, the issue still remains on how to efficiently cache such values or reduce the number of concatenations for generic input. I do not know of an efficient way to do this. Therefore, I think that the tiered map is an efficient solution that eludes the concatenation problem.

Comment: Can you please spell out an example, like search for US_O_P from the question?

Comment: No, it won't. Because, for the DS you suggested, there will be multiple values for the key **US**. BUT, a map doesn't keep multiple values for one key.

Comment: How would you put values into the map? Use OP's `put` examples to put some values into the map

Comment: I have updated the example to show how you could generically add and search for values

Comment: I didn't test the codes, but my feeling is, this is not faster than OP's approach. I think OP's problem is performance stuff, perhaps you could provide some benchmark test?

Comment: @Kent, I have update the example with a performance benchmark. To my surprise it was faster, but I believe the performance issues lies within string concatenation which I have explained in my answer.

Comment: Haha, I almost wrote a comment hinting at the string concatenation when I first read the question... could changing the underlying Map impl make a difference, especially when nesting things?

Comment: You could shorten `addEntry` to a one-liner: `regionMap.computeIfAbsent(region, k -> new HashMap<>()).computeIfAbsent(s1, k -> new HashMap()).put(s2, value);`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need some tree structure to help you encapsulating the logic with the wildcards ("*") replacements when searching for a value.

First I wrote some unit tests to describe the expected behaviour

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class WildcardSearchSpec {
    private Node root;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        root = new WildcardSearch();
        root.add("US_A_B", "1");
        root.add("US_A_*", "2");
        root.add("US_*_*", "3");
        root.add("US_O_O", "4");
        root.add("US_*_W", "5");
        root.add("ASIA_*_*", "6");
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnFullWildcardCorrespondingValue() {
        String key = "US_Q_Q";

        String value = root.value(key);

        assertEquals("3", value);
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnNoWildcardCorrespondingValue() {
        String key = "US_A_B";

        String value = root.value(key);

        assertEquals("1", value);
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnS2WildcardCorrespondingValue() {
        String key = "US_A_U";

        String value = root.value(key);

        assertEquals("2", value);
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnS1WidlcardCorrespondingValue() {
        String key = "US_W_W";

        String value = root.value(key);

        assertEquals("5", value);
    }

    @Test(expected=NoValueException.class)
    public void itShouldThrowWhenNoCorrespondingValue() {
        String key = "EU_A_B";

        root.value(key);

        fail();
    }
}
```

The interface one can extract from these tests is the following

```
public interface Node {
    void add(String key, String value);
    String value(String key);
}
```

Which is implemented by `WildcardSearch`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public final class WildcardSearch implements Node {
    private final Map<String, CountrySearch> children = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void add(String key, String value) {
        String country = key.split("_")[0];
        String rest = key.substring(country.length() + 1);

        children.putIfAbsent(country, new CountrySearch());
        children.get(country).add(rest, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String value(String key) {
        String country = key.split("_")[0];
        String rest = key.substring(country.length() + 1);

        if (!children.containsKey(country)) {
            return children.get(country).value(rest);
        } else {
            throw new NoValueException();
        }
    }
}
```

`WildcardSearch` uses `CountrySearch` to delegate the search in each country.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

final class CountrySearch implements Node {
    private final Map<String, SuffixeSearch> children = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void add(String key, String value) {
        String[] splittedKey = key.split("_");
        String s1 = splittedKey[0];
        String s2 = splittedKey[1];
        children.putIfAbsent(s1, new SuffixeSearch());
        children.get(s1).add(s2, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String value(String key) {
        String[] splittedKey = key.split("_");
        String s1 = splittedKey[0];
        String s2 = splittedKey[1];

        if (children.containsKey(s1)) {
            return children.get(s1).value(s2);
        } else if (children.containsKey("*")) {
            return children.get("*").value(s2);
        } else {
            throw new NoValueException();
        }
    }
}
```

`CountrySearch` uses `SuffixeSearch` to delegate the search in the suffixes.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

final class SuffixeSearch implements Node {
    private final Map<String, String> children = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(String key, String value) {
        children.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String value(String key) {
        if (children.containsKey(key)) {
            return children.get(key);
        } else if (children.containsKey("*")) {
            return children.get("*");
        } else {
            throw new NoValueException();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `NoValueException` is a custom `RuntimeException`.

The point is that each responsibility is clearly separated.

`SuffixeSearch` is only able to return the value for the corresponding key or the value corresponding to "*". It doesn't know anything about how is the overall key structured, nor the values are clustered by country, etc.

`CountrySearch` only knows about its level, delegating the rest to `SuffixeSearch` or ignoring what is above.

`WildcardSearch` only knows about splitting in country and delegates to `CountrySearch` the responsibility to do the wildcard magic.

Answer (score 0):

Best and more general solution would be to use a [Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) which you could implement yourself fairly easily and is a good programming exercise as well. There are also lots of tutorials and examples around, how to implement it.

For your special use case you could make use of cascading Maps, as DragonAssassin aready posted, which leverages what Java already offers.

Answer (score 0):

If prepared right you could nest three maps and mark an entry star for the generic cases (in fact * would just be another key into the maps). To get the desired number you would then need three "Indexes". Assuming there will always be a *-Map:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> map;
 Map<String, Map<String, String> us_map = new Map<String, Map<String, String>();
 Map<String, Map<String, String> asia_map = new Map<String, Map<String, String>();

 Map<String, String> us_a_map = new Map<String, Integer>();
 us_a_map.put("B", 1);
 us_a_map.put("*", 2);

 Map<String, String> us_star_map = new Map<String, Integer>();
 us_star_map.put("*", 3);
 us_star_map.put("W", 5);

 map.put( "US", us_map);
 us_map.put( "A", us_a_map );
 us_map.put( "*", us_star_map );

 map.put( "ASIA", asia_map);
```

In this map the performance will be better than in your proposed case, since the maps are smaller. For example to get element US_A_B you would

```
 Integer value = map.get( "US" ).get( "A" ).get( "B" );
```

To deal with missing elements (in this case the * elements have to be considered) one also can find the Map entry "in each level": With following input:

```
 String l0 = "US";
 String l1 = "A";
 String l2 = "unknown";
```

And assuming there is always an entry for "*" in each of the Maps:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, String>> level_0
 Map<String, String> level_1;
 Integer level_2; // This will be the desired result

 level_0 = map.get(l0);
 if (level_0 == null) {
      level_0 = star_0;
 }

 level_1 = level_0.get(l1);
 if (level_1 == null) {
      level_1 = level_0.get("*");
 }

 level_2 = level_1.get(l2);
 if (level_2 == null) {
      level_2 = level_1.get("*");
 }
```

The Result will then be the value of level_2.

Comment: problem is input params are always specified and never == star. So for US_O_P your example will not return 3

Comment: I have added an edit. Even though adding more search operations is propably not desirable...

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimization is to expand the map to all possible values, it will need more memory and has some initialization cost but it might be worth it.

I made a few assumptions, if they dont apply to your problem this approach is useless for you.

- The region data does not change, (a partial restart is acceptable in the case the data changes).
- It is always one char instead of the "star". So "US_A_B" not "US_AA_BB".
- Only uppercase letters instead of the "star". So no "US_a_b" or "US_/_/"

This approach creates int[] for every region. In this array are all the possible values calculated for 'A'*'A' -> 'Z'*'Z' including the '*'. So for a request you only need to find the correct int[] and calculate the index in the array based on the chars supplied.

I run it with benchmarks from @DragonAssassin and got 1/10 of his approach. The cost is about 1kb of memory for each region.

Here is the code:

```
static class AreaMapBuilder {
    private List<String> areas = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, Integer> codes = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String area, char a, char b, int value) {
        areas.add(area);
        if (a == '*')
            a = '@';
        if (b == '*')
            b = '@';
        codes.put(area + "_" + a + "_" + b, value);
    }

    public AreaMap build() {
        Map<String, int[]> codes = new HashMap<>();
        for (String area : areas) {
            codes.put(area, forArea(area));
        }

        return new AreaMap(codes);

    }

    private int[] forArea(String area) {
        int[] forArea = new int[27 * 27];
        for (int indexA = 0; indexA < 27; indexA++) {
            for (int indexB = 0; indexB < 27; indexB++) {

                forArea[indexA * 27 + indexB] = slowGet(area, (char) (indexA + '@'), (char) (indexB + '@'));
            }
        }
        return forArea;
    }

    private int slowGet(String area, char a, char b) {
        Integer val = codes.get(area + "_" + a + "_" + b);
        if (val == null) {
            val = codes.get(area + "_" + a + "_@");
            if (val == null) {
                val = codes.get(area + "_" + "@_" + b);
                if (val == null) {
                    val = codes.get(area + "_@_@");
                }
            }
        }

        return val;

    }
}

static class AreaMap {
    private Map<String, int[]> codes;

    public AreaMap(Map<String, int[]> codes) {
        this.codes = codes;
    }

    public int get(String area, char a, char b) {
        if (a == '*')
            a = 0;
        else
            a -= '@';
        if (b == '*')
            b = 0;
        else
            b -= '@';
        return codes.get(area)[a * 27 + b];
    }
}

static AreaMap getMap(){
    AreaMapBuilder areaBuilder = new AreaMapBuilder();
    areaBuilder.put("US", 'A', 'B', 1);
    areaBuilder.put("US", 'A', '*', 2);
    areaBuilder.put("US", '*', '*', 3);
    areaBuilder.put("US", 'O', 'O', 4);
    areaBuilder.put("US", '*', 'W', 5);
    areaBuilder.put("ASIA", '*', '*', 6);
    return areaBuilder.build();     
}
```

Comment: Expansion would be a good improvement if it can be done; however, there is no reason both your approach and mine cannot be done at the same time. After a few microbenchmarks, I noticed the char instead of String improved both approaches. I also noticed that three map calls was faster than performing the four concatenations (I.E. `region+"_"+s1+"_"+s2`)